# Oracle Table Index creation

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I created a table named `STUDENT`.  It has the following columns:

- Id
- Name
- Surname
- DateOfBirth
- DateOfAdmission
- DateOfPassout

This table have following primary key:

- Id
- Name
- Surname
- DateOfAdmission

Do I need to create an index another index of column Id, Name if want to query this table providing input just Id and Name?

Comment: Does your primary key really need four columns? Judging by the names, it looks like `Id` should be the primary key (I presume it is always unique). Understand that if your primary key really does consist of four columns, you will end up with a lot of columns in other tables for foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 2):

An index isn't necessary for queries.
An index has the potential to speed up queries if the index can be used, but will slow down INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements.

I'm not clear when Oracle started, but Oracle 10g+ will automatically create an index when a primary key is defined for a table.  That index will match the column(s) that make up the primary key.  Being that the `id` and `name` columns are part of the primary key, the pair is guaranteed to be unique and I don't see the need to create an additional covering index.